# Text stripper stops and waits

Tags: java-8, lucene, pdfbox

I'm trying to extract text from a pdf file, in order to index it with Lucene. This is the code:

```
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(f));
parser.parse();
String text = new PDFTextStripper().getText(parser.getPDDocument());   // stops here
parser.getPDDocument().close();
```

The execution starts waiting indefinitely at the row indicated in comment. I am **sure** the previous row has been executed.

I'm using pdfbox version 1.8.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please with the current version which is 2.0.17.

Comment: I've tried with both versions. The result is the same.

Comment: Then please share the file for inspection.

Comment: I've tried with several files. Nothing changes... :-(

Comment: What happens if you try it with the ExtractText feature of pdfbox-app ? (Download from the download page, then run `java -jar pdfbox-appXXXX.jar ExtractText yourfile.pdf`, txt file should appear in same directory) I'm wondering if "something" will work. Btw correct code to open is `PDDocument.load()` or (on 1.8) `PDDocument.loadNonSeq()`.

Comment: It works normally: text has been extracted in a txt file. I'm surprised!

Comment: What worked: the command line app, or using the API calls? Btw if the API calls don't work, then please use a debugger to find out which calls "hangs".

Comment: It works properly, both the command line call and the API. With the correct syntax it works!
Here is the correct approach:

`PDDocument doc3 = PDDocument.load(f);
logger.debug("Got document...");
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
logger.debug("Got stripper...");
String content = stripper.getText(doc3);`

Thank you very much!

Comment: Very mysterious. But I'm glad it works now. Please answer the question yourself, include the code that worked for you. (Your existing code wasn't "bad", it was only outdated)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I used the PdfBox with 2.0.17 version (not 1.8).

The correct code for getting the text inside a pdf file is the following:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String content = stripper.getText(doc);
```

This works!